# How can I delete a random part of an expression?

Tags: random, expression-manipulation

I have the expression:

`Times[0.19157500241430547,Power[Plus[0.7235014213631388,k,Times[-1,Power[m,c]]],Times[g,z]]]`

Also represented as:

```
0.191575 (0.723501 + k - m^c)^(g z)
```

I want to randomly select either a symbol or real and delete it from the expression, so the expression might become:

```
0.191575 (k - m^c)^(g z)
```

Or maybe:

```
0.191575 (0.723501 + k - m^c)^(z)
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: If there were even a way to use Dimensions[] to get all of the dimensions of the expression, I could use those dimensions to plug in for Delete[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear@expr
expr=0.191575 (0.723501 + k - m^c)^(g z)
Delete[expr,RandomChoice@Position[expr, x_ /; Length@x == 0, Heads -> False]]

(*Original: 0.191575 (0.723501 +k-m^c)^(g z)
New: (0.723501 +k-m^c)^(g z)*)
```

Comment: I would use `Position[expr, _Symbol | _Real, {-1}, Heads -> False]` instead.

Comment: It works, thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

Maybe, as a simple but general utility function, you can use this:

```
RandomDelete[expr_, pattern_, opts___] := Delete[
  expr, 
  RandomChoice[Position[expr, pattern, opts]]
]
```

Then you can use it to randomly delete symbols:

```
RandomDelete[0.191575 (0.723501 + k - m^c)^(g z), _Symbol]
```

Or reals:

```
RandomDelete[0.191575 (0.723501 + k - m^c)^(g z), _Real]
```

And use the `Heads` option that is used by `Position`:

```
Table[RandomDelete[f[x, y], _, Heads -> False], 30]
```

---

I've added this to my `Prototypes` paclet, available here:

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/prototypes/releases/download/v0.4.1/Prototypes-0.4.1.paclet"]
```

(And to uninstall, run `PacletUninstall["Prototypes"]`)

Its documentation page has a few examples on how you can use it:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
deleteRandomCase = DeleteCases[#, RandomChoice[Cases[#, _Symbol | _Real, -1]], -1, 1] &;
```

Examples:

```
Table[deleteRandomCase[expr], {5}] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  0.191575 \left(0.723501\, -m^c\right)^{g z} \\
>  0.191575 \left(-m^c+k+0.723501\right)^g \\
>  \left(-m^c+k+0.723501\right)^{g z} \\
>  0.191575 \left(k-m^c\right)^{g z} \\
>  0.191575 \left(k-m^c\right)^{g z} \\
> \end{array}$